# PARSEDATETIME does not exist

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I'm following [this tutorial](https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular-2-spring-boot-jwt-cors_part2/) and it requires me to make a data.sql file in my resource folder:

```
INSERT INTO USER (ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, ENABLED, LASTPASSWORDRESETDATE) VALUES (1, 'admin', '$2a$08$lDnHPz7eUkSi6ao14Twuau08mzhWrL4kyZGGU5xfiGALO/Vxd5DOi', 'admin', 'admin', 'admin@admin.com', 1, PARSEDATETIME('01-01-2016', 'dd-MM-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO USER (ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, ENABLED, LASTPASSWORDRESETDATE) VALUES (2, 'user', '$2a$08$UkVvwpULis18S19S5pZFn.YHPZt3oaqHZnDwqbCW9pft6uFtkXKDC', 'user', 'user', 'enabled@user.com', 1, PARSEDATETIME('01-01-2016','dd-MM-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO USER (ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, ENABLED, LASTPASSWORDRESETDATE) VALUES (3, 'disabled', '$2a$08$UkVvwpULis18S19S5pZFn.YHPZt3oaqHZnDwqbCW9pft6uFtkXKDC', 'user', 'user', 'disabled@user.com', 0, PARSEDATETIME('01-01-2016','dd-MM-yyyy'));

INSERT INTO AUTHORITY (ID, NAME) VALUES (1, 'ROLE_USER');
INSERT INTO AUTHORITY (ID, NAME) VALUES (2, 'ROLE_ADMIN');

INSERT INTO USER_AUTHORITY (USER_ID, AUTHORITY_ID) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO USER_AUTHORITY (USER_ID, AUTHORITY_ID) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO USER_AUTHORITY (USER_ID, AUTHORITY_ID) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO USER_AUTHORITY (USER_ID, AUTHORITY_ID) VALUES (3, 1);
```

When I run my application I get the error:

> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/alucardu/Documents/projects/movieseat/backend/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO USER (ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, ENABLED, LASTPASSWORDRESETDATE) VALUES (1, 'admin', '$2a$08$lDnHPz7eUkSi6ao14Twuau08mzhWrL4kyZGGU5x
>   fiGALO/Vxd5DOi', 'admin', 'admin', 'admin@admin.com', 1, PARSEDATETIME('01-01-2016', 'dd-MM-yyyy')); nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION movieseat.PARSEDATETIME does not exist

I've checked [a source](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#parsedatetime)

Parses a string and returns a timestamp. The most important format characters are: y year, M month, d day, H hour, m minute, s second. For details of the format, see java.text.SimpleDateFormat.

Example:

```
CALL PARSEDATETIME('Sat, 3 Feb 2001 03:05:06 GMT',
'EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z', 'en', 'GMT')
```

Could someone explain what's wrong in the SQL file?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a MySQL database, and the tutorial isn't based on that engine (`PARSEDATETIME` isn't a function in MySQL)

Comment: Ah okay, so the tutorial is using http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html. Hm okay

Comment: Exactly - it is calling the [H2 function PARSEDATETIME](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html?highlight=PARSEDATETIME&search=parsed#parsedatetime), so you'll need to use that engine to complete/follow the tutorial

Comment: Well I've used https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date STR_TO_DATE which added the records to the mysql database.

Comment: Check all your tables are clear before retesting the query, and also check that `user_id` in `user_authority` isn't a primary key